# Python: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable while using multiple lists in a list

Tags: python, integer, typeerror

Here's the code:

```
l=[['d',4,4,4],['z',26,26,26],['m',13,13,13]]
n=[]
m=[]
for l in l:
    n.append(l[0])
n.sort()
for n in n:
    i=0
    prev=len(m)
    while prev == len(m):
        if n==l[i][0]:
            m.append([l[i][1],l[i][2],l[i][3]])
        else:
            i=i+1
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
>
```

I read several articles and Overflow answers addressing this error. But I am not getting where exactly I am making the mistake.

Comment: @ImThePeak Already fixed your code's syntactical errors but we might be able to help better if you'll tell us what you are trying to do in this code.

Comment: Note - after the first *for* loop, you got *n* is ```d m z```!  Serious mistake in *for l in l* and ```for n in n``` <---

Answer (score 1):

does this help ? i fixed your forloop and if statement :

```
l=[['d',4,4,4],['z',26,26,26],['m',13,13,13]]
n=[]
m=[]
for item in l:
    n.append(l[0])
n.sort()
for item in n:
    i=0
    prev=len(m)
    if prev == len(m):
        if n==l[i][0]:
            m.append([l[i][1],l[i][2],l[i][3]])
            print(m)
        else:
            i=i+1
print(m,n,l)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `l` variable for both list name and in-for-loop-variable. and the same thing for `n`.

try changing the code like this:

```
l=[['d',4,4,4],['z',26,26,26],['m',13,13,13]]
n=[]
m=[]
for l_item in l:
   n.append(l_item[0])
n.sort()
for n_item in n:
   i=0
   prev=len(m)
   if prev == len(m):
       if n_item==l[i][0]:
           m.append([l[i][1],l[i][2],l[i][3]])
           print(m)
       else:
           i=i+1
print(m,n,l)
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem has been resolved due to suggestions from some of you above. Thank you! Although, I'm posting an answer because there are some unneccessary changes in codes posted by you guys above, which are resulting in incorrect output. The mistake which I was doing was using same name for the 'for' loop variable and for the list concerned (for l in l, for n in n).

```
l=[['d',4,4,4],['z',26,26,26],['m',13,13,13]]
n=[]
m=[]
for l_item in l:
    n.append(l_item[0])
n.sort()
for n_item in n:
    i=0
    prev=len(m)
    while prev == len(m):
        if n_item==l[i][0]:
            m.append([l[i][1],l[i][2],l[i][3]])
        else:
            i=i+1
print(m)
print(n)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[4, 4, 4], [13, 13, 13], [26, 26, 26]]
['d', 'm', 'z']
[['d', 4, 4, 4], ['z', 26, 26, 26], ['m', 13, 13, 13]]
>
```